# Remove redundant Field Value using GROUP BY and WITH ROLLUP

Tags: mysql, group-by, rollup

I have 4 `Tables` setup and I have to use `GROUP BY` method:

**'overtime' Table**:

```
ot_id | user_id |       datefrom      |       dateto        
------+---------+---------------------+---------------------
  1   |     3   | 2015-12-21 17:00:00 | 2015-12-21 19:30:00 
------+---------+---------------------+---------------------
  9   |     1   | 2015-12-21 17:00:00 | 2015-12-21 19:00:00 
------+---------+---------------------+---------------------
  10  |     1   | 2015-12-21 17:00:00 | 2015-12-28 18:00:00 
------+---------+---------------------+---------------------
  11  |    45   | 2015-12-21 17:00:00 | 2015-12-21 19:00:00
------+---------+---------------------+---------------------
  12  |    45   | 2015-12-22 17:00:00 | 2015-12-22 18:30:00
------+---------+---------------------+---------------------
  13  |     4   | 2015-12-21 17:00:00 | 2015-12-21 19:00:00
------+---------+---------------------+---------------------
  14  |     4   | 2015-12-21 17:00:00 | 2015-12-21 18:00:00
------+---------+---------------------+---------------------
  15  |     1   | 2015-12-22 04:00:00 | 2015-12-22 08:00:00
------+---------+---------------------+---------------------
  16  |    55   | 2015-12-23 17:00:00 | 2015-12-23 19:00:00
------+---------+---------------------+---------------------
  17  |    56   | 2015-12-23 17:00:00 | 2015-12-23 19:00:00
------+---------+---------------------+---------------------
  18  |    56   | 2015-12-24 17:00:00 | 2015-12-24 18:30:00
```

**'users' Table**:

```
user_id | dept_id | loc_id
--------+---------+---------
    1   |    2    |   58
--------+---------+---------
    3   |    2    |   58
--------+---------+---------
    4   |    2    |   58
--------+---------+---------
    45  |    2    |   58
--------+---------+---------
    55  |    1    |   58
--------+---------+---------
    56  |    1    |   47
```

**'location' Table**:

```
loc_id | location
-------+----------------
   47  | DAGUPAN
-------+----------------
   58  | ADMINISTRATION
```

**'department' Table**:

```
dept_id | department_name
--------+-----------------
    1   | ACCOUNTING
--------+-----------------
    2   | MIS
```

My query:

```
SELECT l.location, d.department_name,
        COALESCE(l.loc_id,'TOTAL') as loc_id,

((LEFT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) - TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')))), 2) * 60)

+

SUBSTRING(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) - TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')))), 4, 2)) / 60

AS totalHrs


FROM `overtime` AS o
INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON o.user_id=u.user_id
INNER JOIN `location` AS l ON u.loc_id=l.loc_id
INNER JOIN `department` AS d ON u.dept_id=d.dept_id

GROUP BY l.loc_id, d.dept_id WITH ROLLUP
```

Giving me this:

[image]

What I want is something like this:

```
|----------------|-----------------|-----------------|--------------------------|
|--- location ---|--- department---|--- totalHrs ----|--- over all totalHrs ----|
|----------------|-----------------|-----------------|--------------------------|
|     DAGUPAN    |   ACCOUNTING    |       3.5       |                          |
|----------------|-----------------|-----------------|--------------------------|
|      (NULL)    |     (NULL)      |       TOTAL     |            3.5           |
|----------------|-----------------|-----------------|--------------------------|
| ADMINISTRATION |   ACCOUNTING    |        2        |                          |
|----------------|-----------------|-----------------|--------------------------|
|      (NULL)    |      MIS        |        16       |                          |
|----------------|-----------------|-----------------|--------------------------|
|      (NULL)    |      (NULL)     |       TOTAL     |             18           |
|----------------|-----------------|-----------------|--------------------------|
```

Is it possible to remove the redundant looping of `location` field?
Also I want to make a new `column` named `over all totalHrs` and get the total value using `WITH ROLLUP`

Thanks in advance!

> **EDITED**

Found this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ee5e/27), and it's just a different table structure. But this is exactly what I want.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins): using old-style JOINs - that old-style comma-separated list of tables style was replaced with the proper ANSI JOIN syntax in the ANSI-92 SQL Standard (more than 20 years ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @davejal, I already edited my question. Care to answer now?

Comment: I don't want to be rude or something, but it would help a lot if the db schema was given as text, not as image.

Comment: And because of image some columns are not shown

Comment: Also I am missing some records (i.e. Dagupan doesn't have any records in the users table), this makes it difficult to reproduce

Comment: I edited my question for further analyzation. Tnx for your response.

Answer (score 1):

No sure where you're going to use this. So I am assuming it's for some kind of report you'll create using a programming environment. Read further why this is important.

1. Removing the loc_id from your query doesn't seem to effect it, so why keep it if you need it?
2. Removing the rollup

   ```
   SELECT l.location, d.department_name,
   ((LEFT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) - TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')))), 2) * 60)
   +
   SUBSTRING(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) - TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')))), 4, 2)) / 60
   AS totalHrs
   FROM `overtime` AS o
   INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON o.user_id=u.user_id
   INNER JOIN `location` AS l ON u.loc_id=l.loc_id
   INNER JOIN `department` AS d ON u.dept_id=d.dept_id
   GROUP BY l.loc_id, d.dept_id
   ```

produces with the data I used (not the same as your data):

```
location    department_name totalHrs
Dagupan accounting  7
administration  accounting  2.5
administration  mis 5
administration  bod 5.5
```

So the rollup you want will add rows at each change in location (suming them up in the total hours row.

Giving you the following:

```
location    department_name totalHrs
Dagupan accounting  7
Dagupan accounting  7
administration  accounting  2.5
administration  mis 5
administration  bod 5.5
administration  bod 13
administration  bod 20 -----This row is the total of the extra rows added 7 and 13
```

If you don't want this as output you can always leave out the with rollup option and use your programming techniques to display the rows generated by this query and summing them up in a separate variable to display them later on.

Here's the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/372ee/2) I used to test.

If you could add the important fields and data required to get your output I could go a little further, if your not using an programming environment.

After your update I created this:

```
    select case when rownum = 1 then location else null end location,
case when rownum = 1 then department_name else 'total' end department_name,totalHrs
from
(select *,
@row:=(case when @prev=loc_id and @predept=dept_id 
           then @row else 0 end) + 1 as rownum,
    @prev:=loc_id ploc_id,
    @predept:=dept_id pdept_id
from
(
SELECT l.location, d.department_name,
((LEFT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) - TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')))), 2) * 60)
+
SUBSTRING(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) - TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')))), 4, 2)) / 60
AS totalHrs,u.dept_id,u.loc_id
FROM `overtime` AS o
INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON o.user_id=u.user_id
INNER JOIN `location` AS l ON u.loc_id=l.loc_id
INNER JOIN `department` AS d ON u.dept_id=d.dept_id
GROUP BY l.loc_id, d.dept_id with rollup ) src) src2
```

[new fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ee5e/58)

**A little extra for you:**

replace

```
case when rownum = 1 then department_name else 'total' end department_name,
```

with

```
case when rownum = 1 then department_name else concat(location,' total') end department_name,
```

Comment: I edited my question for further analyzation. Tnx for your response.

Comment: have you checked it?